# How do i create an object with random value of attributes through for loops in python?

Tags: python

Good day, I can't make the value of my attributes random every time I create an object through a for loop. My goal in this code is that when I instantiate an object, self.hunger and self.boredom of each object have different value from 0 - 20 but every time I print the critters dictionary through a for loop their self.hunger and self.boredom is the same. How can I make it random? And can you explain it to me why my code didn't work? Here is my some pieces of my code. Any answer is greatly appreciated.

```
class Critter(object):
    """A virtual pet"""
    import random

    def __init__(self, name, hunger = random.randrange(0, 21), boredom = random.randrange(0, 21)):
        self.name = name
        self.hunger = hunger
        self.boredom = boredom

    def __str__(self):
        rep = "\nCritter object\n"
        rep += "Name: " + str(self.name) + ", Hunger: " + str(self.hunger) + ", Boredom: " + str(self.boredom)
        return rep 

def main():
    critters = {}
    crit_name = input("What do you want to name to your critter?: ")
    critters[1] = Critter(crit_name)
    choice = None
    while choice != "0":
        print \
        ("""
        Critter Caretaker

        0 - Quit
        1 - Listen to your critters
        2 - Feed your critters
        3 - Play with your critters
        4 - Create another critter
        """)

elif choice == "4":
            crit_name = input("What do you want to name your critter?: ")
            for i in range(len(critters) + 1, 11):
                critters[i] = Critter(crit_name)
                break
            if i == 10:
                print("\nMaximum critters reached. Cannot create another critter.")
```

If you want the whole program to understand my question, I will edit my question. Please help me.

Comment: make default argument `=None` and inside constructor run `arg=def_value if arg is None else arg`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because you are passing the random values as default arguments and they are evaluated only once. Try in this way:

```
import random

class Critter(object):
    """A virtual pet"""

    def __init__(self, name, hunger=None, boredom=None):
        self.name = name
        self.hunger = hunger if hunger is not None else random.randrange(0, 21)
        self.boredom = boredom if boredom is not None else random.randrange(0, 21)

    def __str__(self):
        rep = "\nCritter object\n"
        rep += "Name: " + str(self.name) + ", Hunger: " + str(self.hunger) + ", Boredom: " + str(self.boredom)
        return rep
```

Comment: Good day. Thank you for your answer. But to be honest. I'm not familiar with the "hunger if hunger is not None else random.randrange(0, 21)" can you explain to me the "hunger if hunger is not None else random.randrange(0, 21)"?

Comment: It's the if-else shorthand in python (if else in one line, but you could have made just a normal if else: like this you write less code. What it does is simple: if hunger is None (no value passed) generate a random one, if instead a value is passed (different from None) the value is used

Answer (score 1):

Default parameter values are always evaluated when, and only when, the “def” statement they belong to is executed.

Thus, it is happening before default arguments to functions(or methods) are evaluated only once. So, assign the default values in initializer instead if you want different random values.

```
class Critter(object):
"""A virtual pet"""
      import random

    def __init__(self, name, hunger = None, boredom = None):
        self.name = name
        self.hunger = random.randrange(0, 21) if hunger is None else hunger
        self.boredom = random.randrange(0, 21) if boredom is None else boredom
```

is evaluated only once. Although if None is a valid value passed in arguments as pointed out by @jonrsharpe, then you need a different solution

```
class Nil(object):
     pass

nil = Nil()

class Critter(object):
"""A virtual pet"""
      import random

    def __init__(self, name, hunger = nil, boredom = nil):
        self.name = name
        self.hunger = random.randrange(0, 21) if hunger is nil else hunger
        self.boredom = random.randrange(0, 21) if boredom is nil else boredom
```

Comment: Think it through; what if you want to create a critter that isn't hungry?

Comment: Actually using `hunger or random.randrange(0, 21)` is not correct in this case since both hunger and boredom are supposed to be integers, so if I pass hunger=0 as parameter the random number is generated even though I specified one, because 0 evaluate to False

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for pointing that out, I have changed my answer. I guess this one might work

Comment: You have misunderstood my point; `None` makes no sense as a valid input, **but `0` does**. This is now hugely overcomplicated, just test for `None` by identity rather than truthiness.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to set `hunger` or `boredom`, but also allow it to default to something random:

```
def __init__(self, name, hunger = None, boredom = None):
    self.name = name
    self.hunger = hunger if hunger is not None else random.randrange(0, 21)
    self.boredom = boredom if boredom is not None else random.randrange(0, 21)
```

What you had was, as in [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/221/), effectively:

```
def get_random_number():
    return 4  # chosen by a fair dice roll.
              # guaranteed to be random.
```